# Unwanted black fade in shadow in fade animation in activity enter and exit animation in android

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, android-animation

I can change the animation of showing activity with overridePendingTransition, and using the fade animation XMLs that I have provided in R.anim folder, but however when the animation is showing there is black shadow fade in animation also showing, which is not what I want at all!
The XMLs though work fine with other views and there is no shadows at all.

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
```

and here is the code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(first.this, second.class );
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Do you mean that right before the fade in starts, you see black screen? If so, have you found how to fix it?